# Pygame KEYDOWN not being recognised

Tags: python, pygame, keydown

I am making a game in python pygame and I am on setting up the keyinput and have came across a part where I don't know what to do at all.

All of the variables are defined as there are no errors, but no key detections are being made at all so I don't know what to do.

I have had a look at other questions and tried there answers but haven't solved the problem yet

```
class Player(object):


    def __init__(self, x, y, velocity):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32

        self.velocity = velocity
        self.render()
        self.tick()

    def movement(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print("done")
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.y -= self.velocity
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.y += self.velocity
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.x += self.velocity
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.x -= self.velocity
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    def tick(self):
        self.movement()

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window.WINDOW, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 
        self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.update()
```

There are no errors but when it is supposed to print out "done" it doesn't so I think it has something to do with the KEYDOWN at the start or before that.

Comment: There isn't enough code in your question to allow anyone to answer. What you have basically look OK, so the problem must be elsewhere. Please [edit] your question and add enough code to show where this `for` is being executed.

Comment: @martineau this is part of a file which doesn't have the main loop or window creation as it is part of a player file, I only included this because it seemed like from my code for this file it was all that was needed

Comment: Tyler: I meant that since your code superficially seems like it would work, the problem is likely in when/where/how it's being executed, which can't be determined by what's in your question.

Comment: @martineau I have now added all the code

Comment: Tyler: That's better...but not sufficient. Is the `Player.movement()` method being called from a _main_ event processing loop somewhere, as pygame apps typically have?

Comment: @martineau the `Player` class is being called in the main file and because of the `__init__` function calling `tick()` and `render()` it does call the `movement()` in `tick()`

Comment: Tyler: Calling `tick()` in the `__init__()` sounds like it would only be called once when a `Player` was created—something that doesn't sound like it should be happening as part of the game's main event-processing loop. I think you're overall architecture may be the problem—which again, can't be determined by the code in your question (even coupled with your comments down here).

Comment: @martineau If you mean when it is called in the main file that was my intention so whenever a new object/entity is called it would do everything itself, if this is wrong though, could you tell me

Comment: `__init__()` is called every time a new `Player` class instance is created—which is something I very much doubt should/would be happening frequently in the main event-processing loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay your code isn't complete, but I can see you're trying to move an image or object **up**,**down**,**left**,**right** on the **pygame** display. I recreated your code from what you gave here, and everything seems to be running fine I'm not sure about **K_w**,**K_s**,**K_d**,**K_a** keys though since I don't have the full code and you are concerned with it not printing *'done'*. **NOTE** that I changed them to print something out instead of actually moving an object. the only errors I found is with your exit **pygame.K_ESCAPE** and **pygame.QUIT** events which is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "main.py", line 13, in 
>       for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized

Solve this using *pygame.quit()* together with *sys.exit()*, first *import sys* on top of your code.

this how it looks and It prints out done on KEYDOWN:

```
<code>
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))




while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event) # logs every event happening on the pygame display

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            print("done")
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                print("self.y -= self.velocity") # not doesn't decrement it prints for testing 
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                print("self.y += self.velocity") # not doesn't increment it prints for testing
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                print("self.x += self.velocity") # not doesn't increment it prints for testing
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                print("self.x -= self.velocity") # not doesn't decrement it prints for testing
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() # add this
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() # add this
</code>
```

Comment: This worked thank you, I tried a while loop before but it didn't work correctly, thanks.

Comment: No problem, anytime.

Comment: Once finding another problem of when the moving is supposed to happen it can't as it is an infinite while loop which means nothing else happens. So after looking for a while, I have realised this doesn't work in my case.